# Vue.js: property or method is not defined on the instance, but it is

Tags: vue.js

I have a Vue.js component that looks like this:

```
<!-- MyComponent.vue -->

<script>
  export default {
    render: () {
      return;
    },
    methods: {
      foo() {
        alert('hi');
      },
    },
  };
</script>
```

And then my HTML looks like this:

```
<my-component @click="foo" />
```

When I run this I get an error:

```
Property or method "foo" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.
```

I can't seem to understand what I'm doing wrong here -- all the other SO questions about this error seem to be caused by scoping issues, but I'm just dealing with a simple component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foo` would need to be defined in the component using `my-component`, not in `my-component` itself.

Also, you'd need to do `@click.native`, unless you're specifically `$emit`ing an event called `click` in `my-component`.

If you were to use `@click="foo"` inside of this component on an html element it would work like you expect (a `@click` on a component needs `.native`).

Comment: May i ask you to have a look at a Vue.JS question related with the source code in github of the book 'Full-Stack Vue.js 2 and Laravel 5' by Anthone Gore here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59245577/laravel-vuejs-router-view-does-not-render-the-component ? Particularly take a look at the EDIT: section of the OP .